# Query and Filter a ChangeStream Document with a "dotted field" '.'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a document that looks like

```
{
  components: { weapon: { type: "Sword" }, health: { value: 10 } }
  type: "Monster"
}
```

I am using a [change stream](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/) that is returning

```
{
  operationType: 'update',
  updateDescription: {
    updatedFields: { 'components.weapon': [Object] }
  }
}
```

I want to add a query to the aggregation pipeline to filter out any updates that are **not** for components, i.e. if the type field is updated I do not wish to get an update.

My query looks like

```
{ $match: { "updateDescription.updatedFields.components.weapon": { $exists: true } }
```

however this does not work as the field on updatedFields is 'components.weapon' not components: { weapon: .. }.

If I could use bracket notation I would do

```
{ $match: { "updateDescription.updatedFields['components.weapon']": { $exists: true } }
```

however this is not allowed in MongoDB syntax (or at least it doesn't work).

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a tricky one to grasp, but there are some solid reasons here and the *normal* MongoDB document case would not include such *"dotted fields"*. So there does need to be some special handling.

The basic case here is that you essentially need to convert the `"key"` in the document which contains the "dotted field" to actually be a "string" instead, and then simply look for the presence of `"component"` within that string.

The short case is you basically want a `pipeline` expression for your [`watch()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#changestreams) like this:

```
const pipeline = [
  { "$match": {
    "$expr": {
      "$ne": [
        { "$size": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": {
              "$objectToArray": "$updateDescription.updatedFields"
            },
            "cond": {
              "$eq": [{ "$indexOfCP": [ "$$this.k", "component" ], }, -1]
            }
          }
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
  }}
];
```

What that does is employs [`$objectToArray`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) to convert the `updatedFields` object into an array of `k` and `v` properties instead of the named keys. At this point the resulting values would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "k": "coponents.weapon",
    "v": "Sword"
  }
]
```

That allows the *now array* to be used with a [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operation using the expression from [`$indexOfCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/) which tests for the presence of the string in the `k` property's value. Where it is anything other than the `-1` ( for **not found** ) then any element containing `"component"` within that value would be the only thing kept, and matching elements from the result array.

> **NOTE** If you have MongoDB 4.2, you might want to look at the [`$regexMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) operator, in place of [`$indexOfCP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/indexOfCP/). It should not be necessary for simply testing for the "presence" of a string within a string, but Regular expressions can of course do a bit more if your use case requires it.
>
> Appropriate here, you would probably search from the beginning of string up to the included "dot", replacing inside `cond` for the [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/):
>
> ```
>      "$not": { "$regexMatch": { "input": "$$this.k", "regex": /^components\./ } }
> ```

Since it is returned as an array, you can then test the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) in order to see if the now *filtered* array actually has anything left in it once the `"component"` values have been removed. Where it does not and the size is indeed `0`, then the results are discarded via the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/), which is also the main operator allowing aggregation expressions to be used within a [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) as well.

Of course all that does is *select documents* which are actually valid to return. In the event you might have other changed fields in an `update` result indicated within the Change Stream document, then you actually need to employ the same type of [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) operation on that in order to actually remove the `"component"` fields from the result:

```
  { "$addFields": {
      "updateDescription": {
        "updatedFields": {
          "$arrayToObject": {
            "$filter": {
              "input": {
                "$objectToArray": "$updateDescription.updatedFields"
              },
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [{ "$indexOfCP": [ "$$this.k", "component" ] }, -1 ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Note here the addition of [`$arrayToObject`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/) which essentially *reverses* the process of manipulation used and then actually returns the `updatedFields` content back in it's original form, without the unwanted keys.

---

In order to demonstrate, here is an actual full listing that reproduces changes made to a collection with such a structure and includes the *watcher*  pipeline in order to *mute* the unwanted changes:

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');

const uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';
const options = { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true };

const log = doc => console.log(JSON.stringify(doc, undefined, 2));

(async function() {


  try {

    let client = await MongoClient.connect(uri, options);

    let db = client.db('test');


    // Insert some starting data
    await db.collection('things').deleteMany();
    await db.collection('things').insertOne({
      components: {
        weapon: { type: "Sword" },
        health: { value: 10 }
      },
      type: "Monster"
    });

    // Set up the changeStream
    const pipeline = [
      // Filters documents
      { "$match": {
        "$expr": {
          "$ne": [
            { "$size": {
              "$filter": {
                "input": {
                  "$objectToArray": "$updateDescription.updatedFields"
                },
                "cond": {
                  "$eq": [{ "$indexOfCP": [ "$$this.k", "component" ], }, -1]
                  /* Alternate MongoDB 4.2 syntax
                  "$not": {
                    "$regexMatch": {
                      "input": "$$this.k",
                      "regex": /^components\./
                    }
                  }
                  */
                }
              }
            }},
            0
          ]
        }
      }},
      /* -- Uncomment just to see the k and v structure
      { "$project": {
        "update": { "$objectToArray": "$updateDescription.updatedFields" }
      }}
      */

      // Actually removes the keys and returns only non filtered
      { "$addFields": {
          "updateDescription": {
            "updatedFields": {
              "$arrayToObject": {
                "$filter": {
                  "input": {
                    "$objectToArray": "$updateDescription.updatedFields"
                  },
                  "cond": {
                    "$eq": [{ "$indexOfCP": [ "$$this.k", "component" ] }, -1 ]
                    /* Alternate MongoDB 4.2 syntax
                    "$not": {
                      "$regexMatch": {
                        "input": "$$this.k",
                        "regex": /^components\./
                      }
                    }
                    */
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ];

    const changeStream = db.collection('things').watch(pipeline);

    changeStream.on('change', next => log({ changeDocument: next }));


    // Loop some changes


    await new Promise(async (resolve, reject) =>  {

      let tick = true;

      setInterval(async () => {
        try {
          let { value }= await db.collection('things')
            .findOneAndUpdate(
              {},
              { $set: { 'components.weapon': (tick) ? 'Knife' : 'Sword' }},
              { returnOriginalDocument: false }
            );
          tick = !tick; // flip the boolean
          log({ currentDoc: value });
        } catch (e) {
          reject(e);
        }
      },2000)

    });



  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }


})()
```

Comment: Fantastic and detailed answer, this illuminated how MongoDB operators work greatly for me. Thank you Neil.

Answer (score 0):

Update for Mongo 5.0 -> There is now a `$getField` operator, which allows you to access fields with `.` without having to do the complex manipulation.

It would look like:

```
const pipeline = {
  $match: {
    $expr: {
      $getField: {
        field: "components.weapon",
        input: "$$CURRENT.updateDescription.updatedFields"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If the field you are searching for is not present in the `updatedFields` object, this will evaluate to null and won't match. This is from the documentation:

> If input evaluates to missing, undefined, or null, `$getField`
> returns null.

Here's the link to the documentation: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/getField/